# How to get email id from facebook login in android?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to integrate Facebook API for login functionality in android. I need email Id for respective user. I am getting JSON in response but It has no email Id.How can I achieve to get the email Id.

```
public void getProfileInformation() {
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Profile", response);
                String json = response;
                try {
                    // Facebook Profile JSON data
                    JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                    // getting name of the user
                    final String name = profile.getString("name");

                    // getting email of the user
                    final String email = profile.getString("email");

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        // Dayanand plzz check this log n let me know.

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    });


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Here is code, Where I am getting null in Toast. It goes to catch method.Please help

Comment: Do you want an "email id" or an "email address"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask for the permission : `email` from the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for the `email` permission to the user, otherwise you can't get it.
Once the user grants you the permission, you'll see it when requesting for `me`.

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/

Answer (score 0):

When you first time login at that time you are passing one permission array. so, you have to pass this array for email permission..

```
private String[] permissions = {"publish_stream","email","user_about_me","user_status"};
```